# Which version of Sikuli shall I use?

Tags: linux, jenkins, windows-7-x64, sikuli

I am planning to implement some Jenkins driven tests of one  GUI application which is available for Windows (Windows 7) and Linux (CentOS7) operating systems. to run these GUI tests, I was recommended to use Sikuli. By looking at the available versions, I came to the two following sites:

- SikuliX (http://sikulix.com)
- SikuliX2 (https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX2)

Does someone have some experience with one of the two applications? Can I safely move to SikuliX2?
Moreover, as a constraint, the Linux tests should be running on a docker.
Thanks in advance for your feedback.